# A problem about equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-transformation

In below equilateral triangle $ABC$, $AD=CE$, $DH=GH$. Prove that $BE=BG$

My thoughts: It looksl ike we need to prove that $ABGD$ are on the same circle but I am not sure how to use the condition $DH=GH$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll prove it the other way around.

Suppose we have $AD = CD$. We find the point $G$ on the line $AE$ such that $BE = BG$, and connect $D$ and $G$. Let $H$ be the intersection of $DG$ and $CF$. I'm going to show that $DH = GH$.

Since $\angle BGE = \angle BEG = \angle AEC = \angle ADB$, we have $\angle GBF = \angle FAD = \angle ABF$, which means that $BF$ is the bisector of $\angle ABG$. Therefore we have $\frac{AB}{BG} = \frac{AF}{FG}$.

But we have also $AB = AC$ and $BG = BE = CD$, and Menelaus theorem w.r.t. the triangle $AGD$ and the line $FHC$ says $\frac{AC}{CD} \cdot \frac{DH}{HG} \cdot \frac{GF}{FA} = 1$.

This then gives $DH = GH$.

Comment: Impressive!  But proving from $DH=GH$ from $BE=BG$  is different from the other way around? I mean $A \Rightarrow B$ is different from $B \Rightarrow A$  unless $A \Leftrightarrow B$?

Comment: The trick is that, there is a unique $G$ such that $DH = GH$, again by Menelaus. It then follows from the proof that the $G$ such that $BE = BG$ is exactly the (unique) $G$ such that $DH = GH$. Perhaps I should have used a different notation $G'$...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A,B,C$ be vectors from $O(0,0)$ to $A,B,C$ resp, let $a=A-C,b=B-C$. And let $C$ be $(0,0)$ then.
Let's write all we have:
$D=(1-t)a, E=tb$,
$F$:$F=AE\cap BD$, $AE:ua+(1-u)tb$, $BD:vb+(1-v)(1-t)a$
$$\begin{cases}
u=(1-t)(1-v)\\\ 
(1-u)t=v
\end{cases}$$
$$u=(1-t)(1-t+ut)$$
$$u-t(1-t)u=(1-t)^2$$
[$$u = \frac{(t - 1)^2}{t^2 - t + 1}, v = \frac{t^2}{t^2 - t + 1}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7Bu%3D%3D%281-t%29*%281-v%29%2C%281-u%29*t%3D%3Dv%7D%2C%7Bu%2Cv%7D%5D)
$$F=\frac{(t - 1)^2}{t^2 - t + 1}a+\frac{t^2}{t^2 - t + 1}b$$
$H=\frac{w}2F$
$G=xA+(1-x)E=xa+(1-x)tb$, and, finally $DH=HG$:
$2H=D+G=(1-t+x)a+(1-x)tb$
$$\begin{cases}
1-t+x=w\frac{(t - 1)^2}{t^2 - t + 1}\\\
(1-x)t=w\frac{t^2}{t^2 - t + 1}
\end{cases}$$
[$$w = 2-t,x=\frac{2 t^2 - 3 t + 1}{t^2 - t + 1},
1-x=-\frac{t (t - 2)}{t^2 - t + 1}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7B1+-+t+%2B+x+%3D%3D+w%28%28t+-+1%29%5E2%2F%28t%5E2+-+t+%2B+1%29%29%2C%281+-+x%29+t+%3D%3D+wt%5E2%2F%28t%5E2+-+t+%2B+1%29%7D%2C%7Bw%2Cx%7D%5D)
$$\hbox{Thus }G=xa+(1-x)tb=\frac{2 t^2 - 3 t + 1}{t^2 - t + 1}a-\frac{t^2 (t - 2)}{t^2 - t + 1}b,$$
$$BE=E-B=(1-t)b, BG=G-B=\frac{2 t^2 - 3 t + 1}{t^2 - t + 1}a-\frac{(t - 1)^2 (t + 1)}{t^2 - t + 1}b$$
$$BG^2=(k_1a+k_2b)^2=k_1^2a^2+2k_1k_2ab+k_2^2b^2,$$
then recall $a^2=b^2$, $ab=|a|\cdot|b|\cos\angle ACB=\frac12a^2,$ thus $BG^2=\left(k_1^2+k_1k_2+k_2^2\right)a^2$ [$=(1-t)^2a^2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B%7Ba+%3D+%282+t%5E2+-+3+t+%2B+1%29%2F%28t%5E2+-+t+%2B+1%29%2C+b+%3D+-%28%28t+-+1%29%5E2+%28t+%2B+1%29%29%2F%28t%5E2+-+t+%2B+1%29%2Cx%3Da%5E2%2Bab%2Bb%5E2%7D%2C%7Bx%2Ca%2Cb%7D%5D) $=BE^2$, QED.